# Como es que puedo llamar a una función de JS desde una extension de Chrome?

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy haciendo una extension de Chrome la cual va necesitar llamar a una funcion de la misma pagina en donde cual la misma extension va a ser usada. **Al intentar llamar una funcion de la pagina no la reconoce y no conozco una manera de llamarla ya que una extension no es como un script propio de una pagina** que se ejecuta como cualquier otro script estando dentro de un elemento . Eh buscado por ahi pero nada que se asemeje a mi problema lo mas parecido es llamar a una funcion de un archivo js desde otro lo cual como e dicho no viene siendo lo mismo para una extension.

Comment: No creo que eso sea posible. Lo más probable (por cuestiones de seguridad) es que las extensiones vivan aisladas del sitio web. Practicamente las extensiones usan las APIs del navegador para ejecutar o hacer algo en el sitio web. Por lo tanto nunca te comunicas directamente con el sitio. Escribes tu código, el navegador toma las instrucciones del API y realiza las acciones que tenga que hacer en el sitio.

Comment: Para más información, la documentación menciona eso: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/